# alternative computed field for Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

is there alternative module rather than computed field in Drupal 7 that allow me to get values by selecting the node field visually (GUI) instead of php code , also to be able to change the value each time i add record?

Comment: Why is computed field not good enough? Please try and explain better what your needs are, thank you.

Comment: at least it does not provide me option to add the value manually by my self instead of calculate it every time